# Type aliases for closures

Tags: closures, rust

I would've thought the following code would work:

```
use std::num::{Num};
use std::fmt::{Show};

pub type GradFn<T : Num> = for<'a> fn(&'a [T]) -> (T, Vec<T>);

fn minimize<T : Show, F>(f : GradFn<T>, x0 : &[T]) {
    // some no-op to test types
    print!("{}",f(x0))
}

fn main() {
    let xSquared : GradFn<f64> = |x : &[f64]| -> (f64, Vec<f64>) {
        return (x[0] * x[0], vec![2.0 * x[0]]);
    };
    let (fx, grad)  = xSquared(vec![2.0f64].as_slice());
    print!("{}", fx);
}
```

But I'm getting a compiler error (see [here](http://is.gd/L7s0md)):

```
<anon>:12:32: 14:4 error: mismatched types: expected `fn(&'a [f64]) -> (f64, collections::vec::Vec<f64>)`, found `|&[f64]| -> (f64, collections::vec::Vec<f64>)` (expected extern fn, found fn)
<anon>:12   let xSquared : GradFn<f64> = |x : &[f64]| -> (f64, Vec<f64>) {
<anon>:13     return (x[0] * x[0], vec![2.0 * x[0]]);
<anon>:14   };
```

Comment: I am not an expert in this area mate, but feel that a bit more explanation on what you are trying to achieve would be helpful for those who may be able to answer.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a type alias to a function pointer type and use it in the parameter of a function. The answer below works, but in my actual application, I'll be doing many functions that use the same function signature and repeating the full type seems tedious.

Answer (score 8):

`fn` does not define a closure type; it defines bare function pointers (i.e. pointers to functions defined with the `fn` keyword). That's why you can't assign a closure to a `GradFn`. Instead, you want to use either [`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) or [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html).

There are a few more changes I needed to make to get this code to compile:

- On `minimize`, the `f` parameter as you wrote it receives an unsized type by value, which is forbidden. You also put an `F` type parameter that you don't use. You probably meant to constrain `F` and to use `F` as the type of `f`.
- The compiler won't let us use a type alias in a type parameter constraint; we need to spell out the trait fully. This means the type alias is basically useless.
- I removed the type annotation on `xSquared`, which is unnecessary. This let me remove the type alias completely.

Here's the final code:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

use std::num::{Num};
use std::fmt::{Show};

fn minimize<T: Show, F: FnMut(&[T]) -> (T, Vec<T>)>(mut f: F, x0: &[T]) {
    // some no-op to test types
    print!("{}", f(x0))
}

fn main() {
    let xSquared = |x: &[f64]| -> (f64, Vec<f64>) {
        return (x[0] * x[0], vec![2.0 * x[0]]);
    };
    let (fx, grad)  = xSquared(vec![2.0f64].as_slice());
    print!("{}", fx);
}
```

Comment: good answer. He could also work with bare function pointers in this case ([playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20{%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20x_squared%28x%20%3A%20%26[f64]%29%20-%3E%20%28f64%2C%20Vec%3Cf64%3E%29%20{%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28x[0]%20*%20x[0]%2C%20vec![2.0%20*%20x[0]]%29%0A%20%20%20%20}%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%28f%2C%20grad%29%20%20%3D%20x_squared%28%26[2.0f64]%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22f%3A%20{}%20-%20grad%3A%20{}%22%2C%20f%2C%20grad%29%3B%0A}) )

Comment: Is there any way to maintain the alias? Part of the point here was to avoid repitition if we have multiple functions that take a `GradFn`

Comment: @AriaHaghighi: Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't accept a type alias where it expects a trait bound. However, I just realized I could make this trait bound shorter, so I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: What about creating a subtrait: `trait GradFn<T> : FnMut(&[T]) -> (T, Vec<T>) {}` seems to compile and have the same result.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I don't know if it's intentional that it works; if it is, that's certainly a nice convenience. If it's not intentional and it's eventually "fixed", one could still use this technique by adding a blanket impl (`impl<T, A: FnMut(&[T]) -> (T, Vec<T>)> GradFn<T> for A {}`; it works right now too).

Answer (score 1):

If your `GradFn` is actually going to be a bare function pointer (as opposed to a closure) you can keep the type alias, like this:

```
use std::num::Num;
use std::fmt::Show;

// this type has to point to a bare function, not a closure
pub type GradFn<T> = for<'a> fn(&'a [T]) -> (T, Vec<T>);

fn minimize<T>(f : GradFn<T>, x0 : &[T]) 
    where T: Show + Num {
    // some no-op to test types
    println!("{}",f(x0))
}

fn main() {
    // this is now a bare function
    fn x_squared(x : &[f64]) -> (f64, Vec<f64>) {
        return (x[0] * x[0], vec![2.0 * x[0]]);
    }

    // and this is a pointer to it, that uses your type alias
    let x_sq : GradFn<f64> = x_squared;

    let (fx, grad)  = x_sq(&[2f64]);
    println!("fx: {} - grad: {}", fx, grad);

    minimize(x_sq, &[3f64]);; // works with minimize as well
}
```